# Avoid last event while page refresh

Tags: asp.net

When I refresh the page Last events are "reloaded" as well e.g. trying to insert same data to database.

How can I avoid this? (using C#)

Answer (score 0):

Most simple and very common solution is to redirect the user to a different page (e.g. "thank you" page) once you are done inserting to database:

```
Response.Redirect("ThankYou.aspx");
```

This way if user reloads the page, he reloads the "thank you" page and no action is performed on the server again.

If you want to stick with one page, another common way to handle the problem is using a Session variable as a "flag":

```
if (Session["inserted_to_db"] == null)
{
    //insert to database...
    //......
    //......
    Session["inserted_to_db"] = true;
}
else
{
    //already inserted, ignore or throw error
}
```

Comment: problem 1: Thank u.. but while i press back button and once again reload means its starts to insert the same value . problem 2 : while client side error msg also display after clear the value..  Thanks advance

Comment: I doubt many will bother to go back and press the submit again, if you're worried about it then use the second approach of Session flag. Not sure what you mean by client side error, can you explain?

Comment: After submit insert error means i ll throw exception and i handle that in hidden text filed while window onload i show the error ... if once again refresh it keeps the error..

Comment: Well, that's not your problem - you should just avoid server side problems. You can't really prevent client side events to occur when reloading.